# Possible ways to recover Mutual fund return (India)

Tags: india, mutual-funds

In year 2003(I was a teenager), my uncle took some of my money and invested it under my name on mutual fund in India. Now in 2021, I want to know it's return. Unfortunately, neither him nor I have any document related to the mutual fund investment.
Is there any possible way we could recover the return ? According to the market, the money must have turned into a fortune. Kindly suggest some ways. Thank you!

Comment: The fund itself should have some record of the purchase. I would start by contacting whoever manages the fund.

Comment: @chepner : yes, we thought to reach out to the company whose Mutual Funds we bought. But without any account number or record, they are not showing interest in talking. I just know that it's under my name. I gave my uncle money and he bought it. Now my uncle could be lying that he does not have any paper/record. Is there any way to bust him? He must have bought mutual fund through bank/PAN etc right?

Comment: Do you have a PAN number? If yes, the fund manager might be able to check using that.

Comment: @Sachin they are not able to locate mutual fund account account through PAN. But we found that the mutual fund is depositing some amount of money (fluctuating digits) every year through NEFT in my old bank account. Can this information help in retrieving the mutual fund account?

Comment: @learner57 Yes, you're probably receiving dividends from the fund. Did you provide the account number in which you're receiving funds from/to to the MF company? If yes, then they can help you with steps to verify your identity and do a KYC.

Answer (score 0):

nowadays most of the security is maintained in the Demat account. Although maintaining it in the physical form is still possible. You can ask him like in 2003 did he had a Demat account, if yes then most probably it would have been stored there. You can also email SEBI or NSDL(info@nsdl.co.in) about your situation and ask them for guidance.

Comment: In most common cases, MFs are not hold in DMAT. Also, DMAT asks for yearly rents. As OP does not mention it, I do not think those are hold in DMAT.